# Entity Framework type initializer exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have an entity framework project that is working fine on my machine, but falls over when run from the network.  Recent changes to the project include adding the Dynamic Linq dll (System.Linq.Dynamic)

When I debug it from the network, VS reports:  `The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception`

The inner exception is:  "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"}

I have tried the usual tricks: removing the `packages` directory from the root of the project, uninstalling and reinstalling from the package manager console, but to no avail.

My app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="LGFinance.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LGFinanceEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.LGFinanceContext.csdl|res://*/Model.LGFinanceContext.ssdl|res://*/Model.LGFinanceContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient; provider connection string='data source=lightning;initial catalog=DLGDB;Integrated Security=true;Password=******;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <applicationSettings>
    <LGFinance.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Setting" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </LGFinance.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Can someone point out what I've done wrong?

Comment: When you say "but falls over when run from the network" do you mean the code is running on another machine.  Most likely wherever you're running the code doesn't have the entity framework 5.0 dll.  Check the bin on the "remote" machine and see if it's there.

Comment: Yep, to another machine.  But I have all the dlls (and a couple of related xmls) located in that directory.  Has all been working up until today, and the only real new stuff that I can blame it on is dynamic linq

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your App.config file has Entity Framework 5.0 listed, and some project in your code is still holding onto EF 4.4 and expecting to find it in the App.config file.

Here's what most likely happened: You installed EF 5.0 on a project that was building in .NET 4.0, which makes the version of EF 4.4 instead of 5.0 (since 5.0 is only for .NET 4.5). If you tried to up the project to .NET 4.5 later on you'll still have EF 4.4 on that project. That would require you to reinstall EF again on that project to have the correct reference to EF 5.0.

Give that a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: Not exactly sure what I'm giving a shot, but, I have tried to uninstall and reinstall EF using Nuget.  The uninstall seemed to work , but on reinstalling Nuget said the project already had a reference to EF 5, but won't let me uninstall agin.  An SO answer said to try with the nuget command line to install, so I did that, and it gave a successful install msg, but then followed that with the same: Project already has an EF reference type message.

Comment: You'll need to manually delete Entity Framework from the References in the project, then reinstall EF.

Comment: Yep, it was that - or something like it - I'm still not sure.  Finally got it all pulled out and put back in again properly (I think). Now the Systems guys have to deploy dot net 4.5.  Oops.  :-)

Comment: This is quite confusing, and there must be a more direct solution. I didn't think there was much complexity in simple DLL references in which such a problem could hide!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This has made my day, I really thought I was screwed with my host sever not being able to enable .NET 4.5! I downgraded my two projects in VS2012 after finding this out and the webApp still had a reference to v5 EF whilst the API project had the correct 4.0

Comment: simple reinstall ef in your executable with that App.config 
and it will install the correct version.

Answer (score 10):

All project have to have correct version of EF installed first and then check the following in the App.config file,

1. Make sure **connectionStrings** element is after the **configSections** element.
2. Make sure **startup** element is after the **connectionStrings** element.

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <configSections>
         <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   </configSections>
   <connectionStrings>
         <add name="SchedulingContext" connectionString="Data Source=XXX\SQL2008R2DEV;Initial Catalog=YYY;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=XXX"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
   <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>       
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all, after that just removed the following providers, it worked for me

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Comment: I started my project with EF6 but needed rollback to EF5. The section "providers" are not available in EF5 so removing this fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this problem installing: Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40762

Regards, 
AM